# Redux saga perform multiple HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

How do i perfom multiple http request in redux saga for this payload:

```
 [
  {
    "product_ids": [
      "e331e78b-e954-4de3-9bb3-80827b0d0741"
    ],
    "body": {
      "command": "request",
      "data": {
        "api_key": "errtrt4i548",
        "api_username": "xxxx",
        "vendor_type": 1,
        "from": {
          "from_description": ""
        },
        "to": {
          "to_name": "Fat Rain Films",
          "to_lat": 36.77254990000006,
          "to_long": -1.2711643,
          "to_description": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "product_ids": [
      "9331e78b-e954-4de3-9bb3-80827b0d0741"
    ],
    "body": {
      "command": "request",
      "data": {
        "api_key": "errtrt4i548",
        "api_username": "xxxx",
        "vendor_type": 1,
        "from": {
          "from_description": ""
        },
        "to": {
          "to_name": "Fat Rain Films",
          "to_lat": 36.77254990000006,
          "to_long": -1.2711643,
          "to_description": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And my Saga code is :

```
export function* getQoute({ qoute }) {
  yield put(updateNetworkStatus(true));

  const headers = {
    method: 'POST',
    // credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(qoute),
  };
  const total = 0;
  try {
    const req = yield call(
      request,
      `${API_BASE}/shippings/shipping/initiate_delivery_sendy/`,
      headers,
    );
    console.log(req);
    // total += req.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    //yield put(updateLoadingStatus(false));
  }
}
```

The challenge i am experiencing is finding a way to call my api with the data in my payload. i.e Call the api 2 times or as much as the number of objects in my json payload in the same saga or action.

Comment: I somewhat understood the problem you are trying to convey, just need some clarifications through the code. can you provide the landing of this actions async request?

Comment: @HaiderAliAnjum                                                                                                          ```export function getSendyQoute(qoute) {
  return {
    type: GET_SENDY_QOUTE_ACTION,
    qoute,
  };
}```

Answer (score 2):

For your case you can iterate through the json array and dispatch an action to call your saga with each of the object as payload.

Say I have an array payloads[2] = {obj1, obj2}. Then do

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < payloads.length; i++) { 
yield put({type: YOUR_ACTION_TYPE_FOR_SAGA, payload: payloads[i]});
}
```